# Python 3.5: How to declare an empty set of vectors?

Tags: python, function, syntax

I have a function whose input is a vector and I want to store all vectors who pass the function and have a certain output (True or False).

I am having trouble figuring out where to store all the vectors though.

edit: I meant array, sorry, I'm a bit of a noob.

my function is

```
def true_set(u=[i,j,k,h,n])
```

Then it computes something based on the elements and returns true or false.
The function is an expression using the variables i,j,k,h,n.

Oh and I am running this with nested for loops because I don't know a better way:

```
def generate_set(): for i in [0,1,100]:
    for j in [0,1,100]:
        for k in [0,1,100]:
            for h in [1,10,10]:
                for n in [0.5,10,10]:
                    u=[i,j,k,h,n]
                    if true_set(u)==True:
```

Comment: Please show some code. Python doesnt have a built in vector type.

Comment: you mean a `list`, right? Or, in general, a mutable collection? If so, `set`s won't do since you can't store mutable objects in it. Use a "vector" of "vectors".

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard if I did that then wouldn't I have to specify the element that the vector is being stored into? That is a problem for me.

Comment: You are talking about *lists*, not vectors, not arrays. And function has no concept of variable declarations, to be a pedant, you mean *initialize*.

Answer (score 0):

You basically are doing two common operations

1. Building a number of combinations based on a number of iterables.
2. Filtering those combinations based on a truthiness test.

Python has tools for both of those things.

The `itertools` library has a large number of utilities for generating combinations of things.

```
i_list = [0, 1, 100]
j_list = [0, 1, 100]
h_list = [1, 10, 10]
n_list = [.5, 10, 10]

from itertools import product
vectors = [v for v in product(i_list, j_list, h_list, n_list)]
```

You can also filter based off of a function

```
vectors = [v for v in product(i_list, j_list, h_list, n_list) if true_test(v)]
```

Or a more functional way

```
vectors = filter(true_test, product(i_list, j_list, h_list, n_list))
```

In this case, `true_test` would look something like

```
def true_test(vector):
    if vector[0] > 1:
        return True
    return False
```

Or whatever other tests you're using to decide whether to include a given *vector* or not.